# How can I increase the line spacing in a matrix?

Tags: spacing, matrices, line-spacing

I'm trying to create a `pmatrix` whose components are rather complicated fractions (Christoffel symbols), and the line spacing is too small making the whole thing a bit cramped and hard to read.

Is there any easy way to increase the spacing (about 1.5 the default would be perfect)?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

You could redefine `\arraystretch`. This can be made locally, within a group or environment. For example:

```
\begingroup
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.5}
% your pmatrix expression
\endgroup
```

But you could do it in the preamble too, then it would have effect on all matrices and arrays.

Here's a redefinition of an internal `amsmath` LaTeX macro for customizing line spacing in specific matrices arbitrarily as desired:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][\arraystretch]{%
  \edef\arraystretch{#1}%
  \hskip -\arraycolsep
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \array{*\c@MaxMatrixCols c}}
\makeatother
```

After putting this in your preamble, you can write

```
\begin{pmatrix}[1.5]
...
```

vary the value as you like, with `pmatrix`, `vmatrix`, `bmatrix` and alike, or use it without the optional argument as usually.

I used it similar in my [blog](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/maths/amsmath-matrix/) some years ago.

Complete small example to show the difference:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][\arraystretch]{%
  \edef\arraystretch{#1}%
  \hskip -\arraycolsep
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \array{*\c@MaxMatrixCols c}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1
  \end{pmatrix}
  =
  \begin{pmatrix}[1.5]
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1
  \end{pmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: matrices in two sizes]

Comment: How can one change the stretching in the preamble and have it done? Do one have to write \begin{pmatrix}[1.5] to stretch it?: 

EDIT: OK I found it: just add "\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.5}" in the preamble and you're good to go.

Comment: How would I use this along with say left or right align in the matrix?

Answer (score 61):

By redefining `\arraystretch` you can change the vertical space between the all rows; using the optional argument for `\\` you can control the vertical space for individual lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{pmatrix}
  \dfrac{a}{b} & c\\
  \dfrac{a}{b} & d\\
  \dfrac{a}{b} & e
\end{pmatrix}
\]

\[
\renewcommand\arraystretch{2}
\begin{pmatrix}
  \dfrac{a}{b} & c\\
  \dfrac{a}{b} & d\\
  \dfrac{a}{b} & e
\end{pmatrix}
\]

\[
\begin{pmatrix}
  \dfrac{a}{b} & c \\[1em]
  \dfrac{a}{b} & d\\[2em]
  \dfrac{a}{b} & e
\end{pmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: \\[1em] This is very helpful, thanks.

Comment: +1 for `\\[1em]`

Comment: Perfect, just used [1em] for a normal matrix and it works!

\begin{matrix} a & b \\[1em] c & d \end{matrix}

Answer (score 1):

Individual veritcal spaces can be done with `\\[3pt]` option, horizontal by `\,` or `\!`

```
\[
  \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1
  \end{pmatrix},
  \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\[3pt]
    0 & 1
  \end{pmatrix},
  \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & \!\!\!\! 0 \\
    0 & \!\!\!\! 1
  \end{pmatrix}
\]
```

[image]