# Why a matrix equation is not vertically aligned?

Tags: equations, vertical-alignment, matrices

I'm struggling to make all the matrices in my equation of same height (vertical alignment). I would appreciate if I could get some suggestions. I tried some solutions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164007/making-matrix-elements-larger-vertically) and [there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223497/matrix-equation-align-letters-and-matrices) but it's looks my question is different.
[image: this what I got]

```
\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation} \label{eq:system_dynamics_l}
\begin{bmatrix}
m_1+m_2 & \dfrac{1}{2}m_2 L  \\\[4mm\]
\dfrac{1}{2}m_2 L  & \dfrac{1}{2}m_2 L^2
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\ddot{x} \\\[4mm\] \ddot{\theta}
\end{bmatrix}
+ \begin{bmatrix}
b & 0  \\\[4mm\]
0 & c
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{x} \\\[4mm\] \dot{\theta}
\end{bmatrix}
+\begin{bmatrix}
k & 0 \\\[4mm\] 0 & m_2g\dfrac{L}{2}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x \\\[4mm\]  \theta
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\\[4mm\]  0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: try `\tfrac` for your fractions

Comment: why are you forcing over sized 1/2 via `\dfrac{1}{2}` ? (just use `\frac`)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because `\dfrac` is higher than other elements of your matrices. Here are two possibilities: use `\tfrac` or `\vphantom`s.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
Arguably simplest solution (thanks to David Carlisle)
\begin{equation} \label{eq:system_dynamics_0}
\begin{bmatrix}
m_1+m_2 & \tfrac{1}{2}m_2 L  \\[4mm]
\tfrac{1}{2}m_2 L  & \tfrac{1}{2}m_2 L^2
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\ddot{x} \\[4mm] \ddot{\theta}
\end{bmatrix}
+ \begin{bmatrix}
b & 0  \\[4mm]
0 & c
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{x} \\[4mm] \dot{\theta}
\end{bmatrix}
+\begin{bmatrix}
k & 0 \\[4mm] 0 & m_2g\tfrac{L}{2}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x \\[4mm]  \theta
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\[4mm]  0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

Original proposal 1:
\begin{equation} \label{eq:system_dynamics_l}
\begin{bmatrix}
m_1+m_2 & \tfrac{1}{2}m_2 L  \\[4mm]
\tfrac{1}{2}m_2 L  & \tfrac{1}{2}m_2 L^2
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\ddot{x} \\[4mm] \ddot{\theta}
\end{bmatrix}
+ \begin{bmatrix}
b & 0  \\[4mm]
0 & c
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{x} \\[4mm] \dot{\theta}
\end{bmatrix}
+\begin{bmatrix}
k & 0 \\[4mm] 0 & m_2g\tfrac{L}{2}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x \\[4mm]  \theta
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\[4mm]  0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

In case you want to keep the \verb|\dfrac|s, which is perfectly fine IMHO
\begin{equation} \label{eq:system_dynamics_2}
\begin{bmatrix}
m_1+m_2 & \dfrac{1}{2}m_2 L  \\[4mm]
\dfrac{1}{2}m_2 L  & \dfrac{1}{2}m_2 L^2
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}\vphantom{\dfrac{1}{2}}
\ddot{x} \\[4mm] \vphantom{\dfrac{1}{2}}\ddot{\theta}
\end{bmatrix}
+ \begin{bmatrix}
\vphantom{\dfrac{1}{2}}b & 0  \\[4mm]
\vphantom{\dfrac{1}{2}}0 & c
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
\vphantom{\dfrac{1}{2}}\dot{x} \\[4mm] \vphantom{\dfrac{1}{2}}\dot{\theta}
\end{bmatrix}
+\begin{bmatrix}
\vphantom{\dfrac{1}{2}}k & 0 \\[4mm] 0 & m_2g\dfrac{L}{2}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
\vphantom{\dfrac{1}{2}}x \\[4mm] \vphantom{\dfrac{1}{2}} \theta
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
\vphantom{\dfrac{1}{2}}0 \\[4mm]  \vphantom{\dfrac{1}{2}}0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. However, instead of `m_2g\tfrac{L}{2}`, I'd write `\tfrac{1}{2}m_2gL` to improve legibility.

Comment: @Mico I agree, of course, but I guess that is up to the OP to decide. I only focused on the alignment of the brackets.

Comment: I'd use `\frac` rather than `\tfrac` as shown by the question most of the time forcing `\dfrac` or `\tfrac`  either does what `\frac` would do, or does the wrong thing.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You are right, of course. Except if the OP would start adding `\displaystyle` somewhere. So with your permission I'd like to modify my answer to include your suggestion.

Comment: sure feel free:-)

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way to handle Ratios Of Unusual Size (ROUS) is to increase `\arraystretch` (macro).  Every row starts with a strut of height `\arraystretch\ht\strutbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation} \label{eq:system_dynamics_l}
\def\arraystretch{1.7}%
\begin{bmatrix}
m_1+m_2 & \dfrac{1}{2}m_2 L  \\
\dfrac{1}{2}m_2 L  & \dfrac{1}{2}m_2 L^2
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\ddot{x} \\ \ddot{\theta}
\end{bmatrix}
+ \begin{bmatrix}
b & 0  \\
0 & c
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{x} \\ \dot{\theta}
\end{bmatrix}
+\begin{bmatrix}
k & 0 \\ 0 & m_2g\dfrac{L}{2}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x \\  \theta
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\  0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: +1 for the nicely-placed reference to one of the most memorable scenes in the movie "The Pricess Bride". :-)

Comment: Just to be fussy: I'd put the redefinition of `\arraystretch` _within_ `equation`. The environment grouping prevents unpleasant consequences.

Comment: @campa - right you are.

Comment: @JohnKormylo what is this"1.7"?

Comment: @AlFagera -  \arraystretch is a scale factor applied to the strut at the start of every row of the array row.  1.6 was too small.

Answer (score 1):

I propose a solution based on  the medium-sized fractions from `nccmath` (in my opinion, for numerical coefficients, `\dfrac` is too large, and `tfrac` too small) and `\vphantom{\mfrac{1}{2}` at the relevant places. I also load `cellspace` to add some vertical padding to the matrix rows:

```
 \documentclass{article}

 \usepackage{amsmath, nccmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[math]{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{2pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{2pt}

\newcommand*{\mystrut}{\vphantom{\mfrac{1}{2}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \label{eq:system_dynamics_l}
\begin{bmatrix}
m_1+m_2 & \mfrac{1}{2}m_2 L \\
\mfrac{1}{2}m_2 L & \mfrac{1}{2}m_2 L^2
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\ddot{x} \mystrut \\ \ddot{\theta} \mystrut
\end{bmatrix}
+ \begin{bmatrix}
b & 0 \mystrut \\
0 & c \mystrut
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{x} \mystrut \\ \dot{\theta} \mystrut
\end{bmatrix}
+\begin{bmatrix}
k & 0 \mystrut \\ 0 & m_2g\mfrac{L}{2}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x \mystrut \\ \theta \mystrut
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
0 \mystrut \\ 0 \mystrut
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]