# How to reduce vertical space in matrix?

Tags: matrices

I want to reduce the size of the vertical space in matrix environment and have a result something like this

[image: a more compact matrix]

But at present I manage something like below

[image: Not so compact matrix]

with the following code

```
  $\begin{bmatrix}
    00 & 08 & 10 & 18 & 20 & 28 & 30 & 38 \\
    01 & 09 & 11 & 19 & 21 & 29 & 31 & 39 \\
    02 & 0a & 12 & 1a & 22 & 2a & 32 & 3a \\
    03 & 0b & 13 & 1b & 23 & 2b & 33 & 3b \\
    04 & 0c & 14 & 1c & 24 & 2c & 34 & 3c \\
    05 & 0d & 15 & 1d & 25 & 2d & 35 & 3d \\
    06 & 0e & 16 & 1e & 26 & 2e & 36 & 3e \\
    07 & 0f & 17 & 1f & 27 & 2f & 37 & 3f
  \end{bmatrix}$
```

I can change the font using \mathsf{}, but other than that, how I reduce the vertical space between the rows? I did find things like [array stretch](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14071/how-can-i-increase-the-line-spacing-in-a-matrix) to increase vertical space between rows in matrix, but not something that can decrease the space.

Comment: Did you try `\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{.5}`?

Comment: No haven't tried that, just doing it.

Comment: Thanks, sigur. That worked perfectly for me. I used \renewcommand\arraystretch{0.75}
Was sceptical if stretch could be given a shrinking value.

Comment: BTW, the hexadecimal letters `a` to `f` should not be set in math italics, but upright.

Answer (score 3):

You're probably using `setspace` with the `\doublespacing` option, which gives

[image]

very much like your picture.

Since `\doublespacing` sets the `\baselinestretch` to 1.6667, you can countermand it for arrays with

```
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.6}
```

because 0.6 is the inverse of 1.6667.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.6} % because \baselinestretch is 1.6667

\begin{document}
$\begin{bmatrix}
    00 & 08 & 10 & 18 & 20 & 28 & 30 & 38 \\
    01 & 09 & 11 & 19 & 21 & 29 & 31 & 39 \\
    02 & 0a & 12 & 1a & 22 & 2a & 32 & 3a \\
    03 & 0b & 13 & 1b & 23 & 2b & 33 & 3b \\
    04 & 0c & 14 & 1c & 24 & 2c & 34 & 3c \\
    05 & 0d & 15 & 1d & 25 & 2d & 35 & 3d \\
    06 & 0e & 16 & 1e & 26 & 2e & 36 & 3e \\
    07 & 0f & 17 & 1f & 27 & 2f & 37 & 3f
  \end{bmatrix}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by OP on comments, `\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{.5}` should work.