# ams math environment, missing $ in equation mode

Tags: amsmath

I'm trying to write some report in Latex, and I need to use amsmath further in the code, but since I added this package, the following piece of code stopped working (initially it was between `\\[\\]` instead of `\begin{equation}` and `\end{equation}`).

When I run my code, it stops on the following piece:

```
\begin{equation*} 
\text{d\overrightarrow{u} = } L \text{d\overrightarrow{x} with } L =\left( \begin{array}{ccc} 
\frac{\partial u_{1}}{\partial u_{1}} & \frac{\partial u_{1}}{\partial u_{2}} & \frac{\partial u_{1}}{\partial u_{3}} \\
\frac{\partial u_{2}}{\partial u_{1}} & \frac{\partial u_{2}}{\partial u_{2}} & \frac{\partial u_{2}}{\partial u_{3}} \\
\frac{\partial u_{3}}{\partial u_{1}} & \frac{\partial u_{3}}{\partial u_{2}} & \frac{\partial u_{3}}{\partial u_{3}} \end{array}\right) 
\end{equation*}
```

With the error:

```
Missing $ inserted. 

<inserted text>

               $

l.15 \text{d\overrightarrow{u} = }

                                   L \text{d\overrightarrow{x} with } L =\le..

?
```

I'd be grateful if I could get any help on this. If I missed a similar post, I'm really sorry for that, I checked around before posting.

Cheers
JF

Comment: Isn't `\vec{u}` better than `\overrightarrow{u}`?

Comment: If you want upright differentials I think the correct thing is to define a macro, with the usual recommended definition: `\newcommand*\dd{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}`. Then use `\dd\vec{u} = L \dd\vec{x} \text{ with } L = ..`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from other design issues of this equation:

Using `\text` with mathematical macro contents requires to use `\text{$\somemathmacro$}`.

Some propositions for a better look

- `\vec{u}` looks better than `\overrightarrow{u}`, but `\vv{u}` from `esvect` does even look better (in my point of view), but not for a vector differential quantity.
- Perhaps `L` should be declared as math operator.
- `\frac` should possibly replaced by `\dfrac`

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{esvect}
\begin{document}


\begin{equation*} 
\text{d$\overrightarrow{u}$} =  L \text{d$\overrightarrow{x}$ with }  L =\left( \begin{array}{ccc} 
\frac{\partial u_{1}}{\partial u_{1}} & \frac{\partial u_{1}}{\partial u_{2}} & \frac{\partial u_{1}}{\partial u_{3}} \\
\frac{\partial u_{2}}{\partial u_{1}} & \frac{\partial u_{2}}{\partial u_{2}} & \frac{\partial u_{2}}{\partial u_{3}} \\
\frac{\partial u_{3}}{\partial u_{1}} & \frac{\partial u_{3}}{\partial u_{2}} & \frac{\partial u_{3}}{\partial u_{3}} \end{array}\right) 
\end{equation*}


\begin{equation*} 
\text{d$\vec{u}$} =  L \text{d$\vec{x}$ with }  L =\left( \begin{array}{ccc} 
\frac{\partial u_{1}}{\partial u_{1}} & \frac{\partial u_{1}}{\partial u_{2}} & \frac{\partial u_{1}}{\partial u_{3}} \\
\frac{\partial u_{2}}{\partial u_{1}} & \frac{\partial u_{2}}{\partial u_{2}} & \frac{\partial u_{2}}{\partial u_{3}} \\
\frac{\partial u_{3}}{\partial u_{1}} & \frac{\partial u_{3}}{\partial u_{2}} & \frac{\partial u_{3}}{\partial u_{3}} \end{array}\right) 
\end{equation*}


%With \vv  macro from esvect.sty: 

\begin{equation*} 
\text{d$\vv{u}$} =  L \text{d$\vv{x}$ with }  L =\left( \begin{array}{ccc} 
\frac{\partial u_{1}}{\partial u_{1}} & \frac{\partial u_{1}}{\partial u_{2}} & \frac{\partial u_{1}}{\partial u_{3}} \\
\frac{\partial u_{2}}{\partial u_{1}} & \frac{\partial u_{2}}{\partial u_{2}} & \frac{\partial u_{2}}{\partial u_{3}} \\
\frac{\partial u_{3}}{\partial u_{1}} & \frac{\partial u_{3}}{\partial u_{2}} & \frac{\partial u_{3}}{\partial u_{3}} \end{array}\right) 
\end{equation*}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Erh, `\text{d$\overrightarrow{u}$}` of course not. `\mathrm{d}\overrightarrow{u}`, `\text` has nothing to do here. See LaRiFaRis answer.

Comment: @daleif: I did not say that it is good ;-) I would not use it for myself, but it's not my task to change the document completely

Comment: Actually it is better that you do, others will come by and see the answer and assume this is the *right* way to do this. Unless we tell people that this is not a good idea, Editors will continue to find these arcane solutions in article contributions.

Comment: @daleif: Alright, I will do later on, but now I have too work real life - problems ;-)

Comment: No problem. It is just good to also have future visitors in mind.

Answer (score 1):

In your case it makes no sense to put math inside a `\text{}` command. I would do like the following (taking Manuel's comment and Stefan's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14072) into account):

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cool}
\newcommand*\dd{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][\arraystretch]{%
    \edef\arraystretch{#1}%
    \hskip -\arraycolsep
    \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
    \array{*\c@MaxMatrixCols c}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*} 
    \mathrm{d}\vec{u} =  L\dd\vec{x} \text{ with } L = 
    \begin{pmatrix}[1.3]
    \pderiv{u_1}{u_1} & \pderiv{u_1}{u_2} & \pderiv{u_1}{u_3} \\
    \pderiv{u_2}{u_1} & \pderiv{u_2}{u_2} & \pderiv{u_2}{u_3} \\
    \pderiv{u_3}{u_1} & \pderiv{u_3}{u_2} & \pderiv{u_3}{u_3}
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: there *are* some places where it does make sense to put math  inside a `\text{}` command, although this isn't one of them.  one place where it's appropriate is in some restrictions on `cases` statements.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, unless one is using `cases*` from `mathtools` ;-)

Comment: @daleif -- fair enough, but if a restriction is mixed text and math, `$...$` is still needed there, even if `\text` isn't.

Comment: @barbarabeeton of course. Just trying to get rid of users writing `\text{for } $x>0$ \text{ and } $y<1$.

Comment: @daleif -- i've entered an item in the update list for `amsldoc` to add decent documentation for using `\text`; it's much too sparse as it is now.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, might also be an idea idea to explicitly note: No, it should not be used to mark function names! I see a lot of people using `$\text{Var}(A)$`...

Comment: @daleif -- can we take this to chat?  i've got some questions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21778/discussion-between-daleif-and-barbara-beeton).