# increase the vertical space between rows of a matrix

Tags: formatting, matrices

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{amsmath}%
\usepackage{amsfonts}%
\usepackage{amssymb}%

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\tau_A
\begin{pmatrix} 
x \\ 
y 
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix} 
\frac{4+5x+6y}{1+2x+3y} \\ 
\frac{7+8x+8y}{1+2x+3y} 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

This code has the following output:
[image: LaTeX output]

Is there anyway to separate the elements in the right hand column vector in order to make the fractions clearer to distinguish?

Comment: You can use `\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.5}` before the matrix  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14071/how-can-i-increase-the-line-spacing-in-a-matrix

Comment: the question cited by @Konne definitely has the recommended answer; a visual example would have helped there though.

Answer (score 12):

You can increase specify extra an space to go between the rows after `\\`. You can also make the fractions bigger with `\displaystyle` if necessary.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{amsmath}%
\usepackage{amsfonts}%
\usepackage{amssymb}%

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\tau_A
\begin{pmatrix} 
x \\ 
y 
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix} 
\displaystyle\frac{4+5x+6y}{1+2x+3y} \\[1cm]
\displaystyle\frac{7+8x+8y}{1+2x+3y} 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Here I used `1cm` to show the effect clearly; a space this big is probably excessive.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution with `booktabs` (so as to be sure one addsthe same vertical space throughout the document) or with `cellspace`:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{amsmath}%
\usepackage{amsfonts}%
\usepackage{amssymb}%
\usepackage{booktabs}
\setlength\defaultaddspace{0.5ex}
\usepackage[math]{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{3pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{3pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \texttt{With booktabs: }\qquad\tau_A
  \begin{pmatrix}
  x \\
  y
  \end{pmatrix}
  =
  \begin{pmatrix}
  \frac{4+5x+6y}{1+2x+3y} \\
  \addlinespace
  \frac{7+8x+8y}{1+2x+3y}
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
  \texttt{With cellspace: }\qquad\tau_A
  \begin{pmatrix}
  x \\
  y
  \end{pmatrix}
  =
  \begin{pmatrix}
  \frac{4+5x+6y}{1+2x+3y} \\
  \frac{7+8x+8y}{1+2x+3y}
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]