# pmatrix makes a 2 by 2 matrix too tall

Tags: matrices, brackets, rendering

I have this piece of code

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
n_1 &= Tr (O^{eff} \sigma_1 ) \\
&= Tr\Bigg [O^{eff} \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \Bigg ] \\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

and I get this when I compile with texmaker

[image]

Copy-pasted the same code in Overleaf, the 2x2 matrix looks normal. Any ideas?

Here is a list of the packages I use:

```
\usepackage{siunitx}  
\usepackage{dcolumn}  
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{bbold}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{appendix}
```

Comment: Please make this into a fully compilable minimal example that others can copy and test without having to add anything. This greatly increase your chances of getting help. For example the preamble you gave plus a naive doc, does not give the image you provide.

Comment: Managed to solve the problem by using the answer from :http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14071/how-can-i-increase-the-line-spacing-in-a-matrix

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide complete document, by which you "produce" your equation ... so I can't say anything, what is cause. Anyway, with following MWE, I can't reproduce your result:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\eff}{eff}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Tr}{Tr}


\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
\begin{split}
n_1 & = \Tr \Big(O^{\eff} \sigma_1 \Big) \\
    & = \Tr\Bigg [O^{\eff} 
    \begin{pmatrix} 
        0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 
    \end{pmatrix} \Bigg ] \\
\end{split}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

In above MWE I take liberty to make some changes:

- for `Tr` and `eff` I suggest to use upright fonts. For this seems to be used `\DeclareMathOperator{...}{...}` macro
- I increase parent in the first row of equation
- for math I use `mathtools` packages ("enhanced" version of `amsmath`