# Getting a missing $ inserted error at d' = a * d * \alpha . Any idea where it is?

Tags: math-mode, matrices

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item 
Applying 2 fold symmetry // X$_1$ :
\\
\\
\[
a=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & -1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & -1 
  \end{bmatrix}
\]
\\
\[
\alpha =
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
  \end{bmatrix}
\]
\\
Applying 3 fold symmetry // X$_3$: 
\\
\\
\[
a=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{1}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & 0 \\
    \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 
  \end{bmatrix}
\]
\\
\[
\alpha_1 =
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
  \end{bmatrix}
\]
\\
For d$_{im}$,
\\
d' = a * d * \alpha
\[
    \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{1}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & 0 \\
    \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 
    \end{bmatrix}

    \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{1}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & 0 \\
    \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 
    \end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `d' = a * d * \alpha` is outside math mode, but it needs math mode: `$d' = a * d * \alpha$`. But the whole code is ugly. You should avoid `\\ ` before and after `\[…\]`. You should not use `X$_3$` but `$X_3$` etc.

Comment: Or perhaps something like `$\text{x}_3`, if the intent is a non-italic variable. (My memory is fuzzy on the correct command to use, though. `\mathrm` instead?)

Answer (score 14):

**Adaptations:**

- math mode for `d' = a * d * \alpha`
- no linebreak inside `\[ ... \]`
- use `align*` instead of `\[ ... \]`
- use `\cdot` instead of `*`
- use linebreaks instead of `\\`
- use `$X_1$` instead of `X$_1$`
- you can use `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}` to increase the spacing of the matrices with the fractions (see [How can I increase the line spacing in a matrix?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14071/123129)) or write the fractions with `$a/b$` as JPi suggested.

**Code:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item 
    Applying 2 fold symmetry // $X_1$:
    \begin{align*}
        a &=
          \begin{bmatrix}
            1 & 0 & 0 \\
            0 & -1 & 0 \\
            0 & 0 & -1
          \end{bmatrix}
        \\
        \alpha &=
        \begin{bmatrix}
            1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
            0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
            0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
            0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
    \end{align*}

    Applying 3 fold symmetry // $X_3$: 
    \begin{align*}
        a &=
        {
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
        \begin{bmatrix}
            \frac{1}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & 0 \\
            \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
            0 & 0 & 1 
        \end{bmatrix}
        }
        \\
        \alpha_1 &=
        \begin{bmatrix}
            1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
            0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
            0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
            0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
    \end{align*}

    For $d_{im}$,
    $d' = a \cdot d \cdot \alpha$
    {
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \begin{align*}
         \begin{bmatrix}
             \frac{1}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & 0 \\
             \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
             0 & 0 & 1 
         \end{bmatrix}
        \\
         \begin{bmatrix}
             \frac{1}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & 0 \\
             \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
             0 & 0 & 1 
         \end{bmatrix}
    \end{align*}
    }
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: You've forgotten to *list* the adaption `$X_1$` instead of `X$_1$`. Nevertheless +1 for listing all adaptions!

Comment: You may want to increase the spacing in the matrices or better yet: write $\sqrt{3}/2$ instead of $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$.

Comment: Thank you Schweinebacke and JPi. I added your suggestions to the answer.

Comment: the width of the matrices in the first two blocks makes it easy to identify them as separate.  but it wouldn't hurt to have a *little* vertical space between the two in the last block.  add with an option after the double backslash separating them, say `\\[3pt]` and be sure *not* to leave a (typed) space between the second backslash and the `[`.

Answer (score 2):

I did not do much, just corrected some shells
- for `\alpha`, it can only be used in a mathematical environment, either `$\alpha$` or  `\[\alpha\]`
it is possible to print the `\alpha` character in a text, but then it is `\textalpha`.
so I will avoid writing
`X$_1$` but rather `$X_1$` to leave its coherence to the mathematical text.
I also corrected some spaces generating in the mathematical formulas

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item 
Applying 2 fold symmetry // X$_1$ :
\\
\\
\[
a=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & -1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & -1 
  \end{bmatrix}
\]
\\
\[
\alpha =
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
  \end{bmatrix}
\]
\\
Applying 3 fold symmetry // X$_3$: 
\\
\\
\[
a=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{1}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & 0 \\
    \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 
  \end{bmatrix}
\]
\\
\[
\alpha_1 =
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
  \end{bmatrix}
\]
\\
For d$_{im}$,
\\
$d' = a * d * \alpha$
\[
    \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{1}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & 0 \\
    \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 
    \end{bmatrix}\\
    \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{1}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & 0 \\
    \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 
    \end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```