# How to make comma align with the bottom of mathematical equations

Tags: math-mode

How do you make commas in mathematical equations align with the bottom of mathematical equations, looking something like this:
[image]

```
\linespread{0.6}

$\begin{bmatrix}[1.6] a\\b\\ \end{bmatrix}$\\
\-\hspace{3.5ex}$^{,}$
```

Instead of the normal behaviour, which puts the comma in the middle

```
$\begin{bmatrix} a\\b\\ \end{bmatrix},$
```

Similar behaviour with tall maths equations. Is there a way to correct these?

(The [1.6] is from here:[How can I increase the line spacing in a matrix?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14071/how-can-i-increase-the-line-spacing-in-a-matrix))

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: Why would you want that? Where do `+` or `-` sit? Well, the comma should sit at the same height.

Comment: Your example shows inline mode (`$` delimiters).  Is that the intended use, or is it desired in display math mode?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
\def\lowcomma{_{\textstyle,}}
```

and you can use it:

```
${\begin{bmatrix}[1.6] a\\b\\ \end{bmatrix}}\lowcomma$
```

Answer (score 2):

This approach uses `\smallmatrix` to get an inline matrix that doesn’t leave the text baseline, and `adjustbox` to lower the comma by the amount of its height. It declares the `\lowcomma` as math punctuation to get the spacing right.

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\newlength\commaheight

\newcommand\lowcomma{%
\settoheight{\commaheight}{\text{,}}%
\mathpunct{\adjustbox{valign=b,raise=-\commaheight}{\text{,}}}%
}

\begin{document}
\linespread{0.6}

\( \left[\begin{smallmatrix} a\\b\\ \end{smallmatrix}\right]
\lowcomma
\)
\end{document}
```

[image]