# Matrices upper triangular alignment

Tags: matrices, typography

I was writing an upper triangular matrix but due to large entry was unable to get in a good view.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
   $$ J(\hat{\Phi})(p)=
   \begin{pmatrix*}[c]
   ((\hat{\Phi}(p)_{ij}))_{i,j=1}^r    &\hdots &   &  &\hdots   &                 ((\hat{\Phi}(p)_{ij}))_{i,j=1}^r                                  \\
  & \ddots      &     &    \vdots\\
         &      & \ddots    & &((\partial^{\alpha}\partial^{\beta}\hat{\Phi}(p)_{ij}))_{i,j=1}^r  &   \vdots        \\
 \text{\huge0} &  &   &       &     \\
 & & & & & ((\partial_d^{k-1}\hat{\Phi}(p)_{ij}))_{i,j=1}^r
\end{pmatrix*}
$$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Probably you like the alignment better if you increase the row height inside of the matrix by redefining the `\arraystretch` (See also: [How can I increase the line spacing in a matrix?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14071/134144))

Comment: This also didn't helped me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are open to loading `tikz`, you could do

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}
\[ J(\widehat{\Phi})(p)=
   \begin{pmatrix*}[c]
   \tikzmarknode{tl}{((\widehat{\Phi}(p)_{ij}))_{i,j=1}^r}   & 
   \hspace*{9em}&
    \tikzmarknode{tr}{((\widehat{\Phi}(p)_{ij}))_{i,j=1}^r}    \\[4em]
 \tikzmarknode{bl}{~} &  &
 \tikzmarknode{br}{((\partial_d^{k-1}\widehat{\Phi}(p)_{ij}))_{i,j=1}^r}
\end{pmatrix*}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,Dotted/.style={%https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/101263/194703
 line width=#1, line cap=round, dash pattern=on 0pt off 4\pgflinewidth},
 Dotted/.default=1.5pt,shorten/.style={shorten >=#1/2,shorten <=#1/2}]
 \draw[Dotted,shorten=4ex]  (tl) -- (tr);
 \draw[Dotted,shorten=4ex]  (tr) -- (br);
 \draw[Dotted,shorten=5ex]  (tl) -- (br) node[pos=0.5,inner sep=0pt,above
 right]
  {$((\partial^{\alpha}\partial^{\beta}\widehat{\Phi}(p)_{ij}))_{i,j=1}^r$} ;
 \node[scale=3,above] at (bl.south west) {$0$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

You could also work with `nicematrix` (which uses Ti*k*Z).

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
\[ J(\widehat{\Phi})(p)=
   \begin{pNiceMatrix}[name=mymatrix]
   ((\widehat{\Phi}(p)_{ij}))_{i,j=1}^r   & 
   \Cdots \Hspace*{7em}& ((\widehat{\Phi}(p)_{ij}))_{i,j=1}^r\\[2em]
   &\Ddots & \Vdots \\[2em]
 ~ &  & 
  ((\partial_d^{k-1}\widehat{\Phi}(p)_{ij}))_{i,j=1}^r\\
\end{pNiceMatrix}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
 \path (mymatrix-1-1) -- (mymatrix-3-3)
 node[pos=0.5,above right,inner sep=0pt]
   {$((\partial^{\alpha}\partial^{\beta}\widehat{\Phi}(p)_{ij}))_{i,j=1}^r$} ;
  \node[scale=3,above] at (mymatrix-3-1) {$0$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am getting errors with the code. `Undefined control sequence. \tikzmarknode`

`Package pgf Error: No shape named tl is known. \draw[Dotted,shorten=4ex] (tl)`

Comment: @XYZABC Then you have a rather old version of `tikzmark` on your computer. Are you using overleaf or can you update your installation?

Comment: Just yesterday I installed texlive full in my Ubuntu. Let me try in overleaf.

Comment: @XYZABC overleaf won't help. You could remove `\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}` and add `\newcommand{\tikzmarknode}[3][]{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,
baseline={(#2.base)}]
 \node(#2){\ensuremath{#3}};
\end{tikzpicture}}`, this should work. I updated a few days ago and know that `\tikzmarknode` has been added a bit more than a year ago to the library.

Comment: Thanks, it worked.

Comment: But the problem is that the middle entry is not on the diagonal. It is in the upper triangle in between.

Comment: @XYZABC I see. Moved it and added second possibility.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. It is again showing `Package pgf Error: No shape named mymatrix-1-1 is known. \path (mymatrix-1-1)`

Comment: The first code worked, second one does not.

Answer (score 6):

Here are two versions as I am not sure if you want the central element on or off the diagonal

[image]

[image]

where

- I have used`\mathrlap` to hide the subscript and superscript from affecting column width so that the `\ddots` appear below them,
- used `\smash` on the large zero so it does not effect vertical spacing,
- used `\multicolumn{}{}{}` for the case on central element being off the diagonal, and
- eliminated unneeded packages for this example.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand*{\A}{((\hat{\Phi}(p)_{ij}))\mathrlap{{}_{i,j=1}^r}}%
\newcommand*{\B}{((\partial^{\alpha}\partial^{\beta}\hat{\Phi}(p)_{ij}))\mathrlap{{}_{i,j=1}^r}}%
\newcommand*{\C}{((\partial_d^{k-1}\hat{\Phi}(p)_{ij}))_{i,j=1}^r}
\newcommand*{\BigZ}{\hspace*{2.0em}\smash{\text{\Huge0}}}

\begin{document}
\[ 
   J(\hat{\Phi})(p)=
   \begin{pmatrix*}[c]
     \A  &        & \hdots  &  \hdots & \A     \\
         & \ddots &         &         & \vdots \\
         &        & \B      &         & \vdots \\
   \BigZ &        &         & \ddots  & \vdots \\
         &        &         &         & \C     \\
\end{pmatrix*}
\]
\end{document}
```

### Code: Central Element off Diagonal

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand*{\A}{((\hat{\Phi}(p)_{ij})){{}_{i,j=1}^r}}%
\newcommand*{\B}{((\partial^{\alpha}\partial^{\beta}\hat{\Phi}\mathrlap{(p)_{ij})){}_{i,j=1}^r}}%
\newcommand*{\C}{((\partial_d^{k-1}\hat{\Phi}(p)_{ij}))_{i,j=1}^r}
\newcommand*{\BigZ}{\hspace*{2.0em}\smash{\text{\Huge0}}}

\begin{document}
\[ 
   J(\hat{\Phi})(p)=
   \begin{pmatrix*}[c]
     \A  & \hdots & \hdots  &  \hdots   &  \hdots    & \A     \\
         & \ddots &         &           &            & \vdots \\
         &        & \ddots  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\B} & \vdots \\
   \BigZ &        &         & \ddots    &            & \vdots \\
         &        &         &           & \ddots     & \vdots \\
         &        &         &           &            & \C     \\
\end{pmatrix*}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think this is not what the OP would like, they don't want the central element on the diagonal.

Comment: @CarLaTeX: Ok, was not sure about that so have provided both versions now.

Comment: Thanks for this. I want the second one.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[
\setlength\arraycolsep{2.5pt} % default value: 5pt
J(\widehat{\Phi})(p)=
\begin{pmatrix}
\bigl((\widehat{\Phi}(p)^{}_{ij})\bigr)_{i,j=1}^r &\dots &\dots & \dots & 
       \bigl((\widehat{\Phi}(p)^{}_{ij})\bigr)_{i,j=1}^r \\
& \ddots & \vdots & & \vdots\\
& &\bigl((\partial^{\alpha}\partial^{\beta}\widehat{\Phi}(p)^{}_{ij})\bigr)_{i,j=1}^r & & \vdots \\
 & & & \ddots  & \vdots \\
 \hbox{\huge0} & & & & \bigl((\partial_d^{k-1}\widehat{\Phi}(p)^{}_{ij})\bigr)_{i,j=1}^r
\end{pmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think this is not what the OP would like, they don't want the central element on the diagonal

Comment: @CarLaTeX - Indeed, one of the [other answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/507686/5001)  does not place the "central element" on the main diagonal. However, below that answer, the OP has posted a comment that "the problem is that the middle entry is *not* on the diagonal" [emphasis added]. Let's see if the OP clarifies his/her formatting objectives.

Comment: I think with "But the problem is that the middle entry is not on the diagonal. It is in the upper triangle in between." the OP intends the middle entry should not be on the diagonal, it should be in the upper triangle. See the picture of their question.

Comment: @CarLaTeX - The OP's comment that you and I quote was posted *before* [Schrödinger's cat](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/194703/schrödingers-cat) posted an addendum to his (her?) initial answer. I honestly cannot detect much of a difference between the two screenshots, at least as far as the position of the "central element" is concerned. Let's see if the OP provides some much-needed clarification.

Comment: See here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/507659/matrices-upper-triangular-alignment/507672?noredirect=1#comment1282942_507672