# How to write code for the following matrix?

Tags: amsmath, matrices

Can you help me to write code for the following matrix...
I have done one part of the code:

```
\begin{displaymath}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
a_{12} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{displaymath}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX - LaTeX! try to elaborate a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) ;)
Then, update your question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can nest the `matrix` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        \mathop{\mathbf{adj}}
        \begin{pmatrix}
            a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
            a_{12} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
            a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}
        \end{pmatrix}
        =
        \begin{pmatrix}
            +
            \begin{vmatrix}
                a_{22} & a_{23} \\
                a_{32} & a_{33}
            \end{vmatrix} &
            -
            \begin{vmatrix}
                a_{12} & a_{13} \\
                a_{32} & a_{33}
            \end{vmatrix} &
            +
            \begin{vmatrix}
                a_{12} & a_{13} \\
                a_{22} & a_{23} \\
            \end{vmatrix} \\[1.5em]
            -
            \begin{vmatrix}
                a_{21} & a_{23} \\
                a_{31} & a_{33}
            \end{vmatrix} &
            +
            \begin{vmatrix}
                a_{11} & a_{13} \\
                a_{31} & a_{33}
            \end{vmatrix}&
            -
            \begin{vmatrix}
                a_{11} &  a_{13} \\
                a_{21} &  a_{23}
            \end{vmatrix} \\[1.5em]
            +
            \begin{vmatrix}
                a_{21} & a_{22} \\
                a_{31} & a_{32}
            \end{vmatrix} &
            -
            \begin{vmatrix}
            a_{11} & a_{12} \\
            a_{21} & a_{22}
            \end{vmatrix} &
            +
            \begin{vmatrix}
                a_{11} & a_{12} \\
                a_{21} & a_{22}
            \end{vmatrix}
        \end{pmatrix}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Turns out there was no need to use the suggestions in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14071/177

Comment: Thanks so much, what I should do to make a spacing between rows inside matrice? :)

Comment: @Amela112 you can use `\\[2mm]` for example

Comment: the spacing between the rows is achieved with `\\[1.5em]`, with `1.5em` a length of your liking (that is, you can change this value).
For a more elaborate solution, have a loot at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14071/177

Answer (score 6):

As suggested in other answers, it's better to use some shorthands.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\minor}[4]{%
  \begin{vmatrix} a_{#1} & a_{#2} \\ a_{#3} & a_{#4} \end{vmatrix}
}

\begin{document}

\[
\operatorname{adj}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
+\minor{22}{23}{32}{33} & -\minor{12}{13}{32}{33} & +\minor{12}{13}{22}{23}
\\ \noalign{\vspace{1ex}}
-\minor{21}{23}{31}{33} & +\minor{11}{13}{31}{33} & -\minor{11}{13}{21}{23}
\\ \noalign{\vspace{1ex}}
+\minor{21}{22}{31}{32} & -\minor{11}{12}{31}{32} & +\minor{11}{12}{21}{22}
\end{pmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The challenge is now to make TeX compute the adjoint itself. Here's a set of macros tha do it.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\adjointmatrix}{O{a}m}
 {% #1 = entry, #2 = number of rows
  \tl_clear:N \l__amela_matrix_body_tl
  \__amela_matrix_adjoint_make:nn { #1 } { #2 }
  \begin{pmatrix}
  \tl_use:N \l__amela_matrix_body_tl
  \end{pmatrix}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__amela_matrix_adjoint_make:nn
 {
  \int_step_inline:nn { #2 }
   {
    \int_step_inline:nn { #2 }
     {
      \int_compare:nF { ####1 = 1 } { \tl_put_right:Nn \l__amela_matrix_body_tl { & } }
      \tl_put_right:Nx \l__amela_matrix_body_tl
       {
        \int_if_odd:nTF { ##1+####1 } { - } { + }
       }
      \tl_put_right:Nn \l__amela_matrix_body_tl { \begin{vmatrix} }
      \__amela_matrix_adjoint_minor:nnnn { #1 } { #2 } { ####1 } { ##1 }
      \tl_put_right:Nn \l__amela_matrix_body_tl { \end{vmatrix} }
     }
    \int_compare:nT { ##1 < #2 }
     {
      \tl_put_right:Nn \l__amela_matrix_body_tl { \\ \noalign{\vspace{1ex}} }
     }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__amela_matrix_adjoint_minor:nnnn
 {% #1 = entry, #2 = size, #3 = row index, #4 = column index
  \tl_clear:N \l__amela_matrix_minor_body_tl
  \int_step_inline:nn { #2 }
   {
    \int_compare:nF { ##1 = #3 }
     {
      \tl_put_right:Nn \l__amela_matrix_minor_body_tl { \use_none:n } % remove the initial &
      \int_step_inline:nn { #2 }
       {
        \int_compare:nF { ####1 = #4 }
         {
          \tl_put_right:Nn \l__amela_matrix_minor_body_tl { & #1\sb{##1####1} }
         }
       }
      \tl_put_right:Nn \l__amela_matrix_minor_body_tl { \\ }
     }
   }
  \tl_put_right:NV \l__amela_matrix_body_tl \l__amela_matrix_minor_body_tl
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\squarematrix}{O{a}m}
 {% #1 = entry, #2 = number of rows
  \tl_clear:N \l__amela_matrix_body_tl
  \__amela_matrix_make:nn { #1 } { #2 }
  \begin{pmatrix}
  \tl_use:N \l__amela_matrix_body_tl
  \end{pmatrix}
 }

\tl_new:N \l__amela_matrix_body_tl
\tl_new:N \l__amela_matrix_minor_body_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__amela_matrix_make:nn
 {
  \int_step_inline:nn { #2 }
   {
    \int_step_inline:nn { #2 }
     {
      \int_compare:nF { ####1 = 1 } { \tl_put_right:Nn \l__amela_matrix_body_tl { & } }
      \tl_put_right:Nn \l__amela_matrix_body_tl { #1\sb{##1 ####1} }
     }
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__amela_matrix_body_tl { \\ }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
\squarematrix{3} \squarematrix[b]{4}
\]

\[
\operatorname{adj}\squarematrix{3}=\adjointmatrix{3}
\]

\[
\operatorname{adj}\squarematrix{2}=\adjointmatrix{2}
\]

\[
\adjointmatrix[b]{4}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is the output of `\adjointmatrix{5}` (you need large paper size for it).

[image]

Comment: Impressive :-) code and creative.

Answer (score 5):

There are many possibilities to create the complete code for your answer. I have chosen a short classic way: put on every row 3 matrix. I have given a small vertical space with `[3ex]`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\adj}{adj}
\begin{document}
\[
\adj \begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
a_{12} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
+\begin{vmatrix} a_{22} & a_{23} \\ a_{32} & a_{33} \end{vmatrix} &
-\begin{vmatrix} a_{12} & a_{13} \\ a_{32} & a_{33} \end{vmatrix} &
+\begin{vmatrix} a_{12} & a_{13} \\ a_{22} & a_{23} \end{vmatrix} \\[3ex]
-\begin{vmatrix} a_{21} & a_{23} \\ a_{31} & a_{33} \end{vmatrix} &
+\begin{vmatrix} a_{11} & a_{13} \\ a_{31} & a_{33} \end{vmatrix} &
-\begin{vmatrix} a_{11} & a_{13} \\ a_{21} & a_{23} \end{vmatrix} \\[3ex]
+\begin{vmatrix} a_{21} & a_{22} \\ a_{31} & a_{32} \end{vmatrix} &
-\begin{vmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} \end{vmatrix} &
+\begin{vmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} \end{vmatrix} 
\end{pmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

This is my output:

[image]

Comment: +1. I'd leave a bit more space between the right-hand edge of a `vmatrix` and the next `+` or `-` symbol, as otherwise uninitiated readers might assume that the determinants in a given row are added (or subtracted).

Comment: @Mico You, like so many other users, are always welcome. The best users can edit, delete, improve what they want of my answers. I am a modest user and I want to be thus. :-)

Comment: I've taken you up on your offer. :-)

Comment: @Mico Very good, and I thank you and everyone.

Answer (score 4):

Just for fun: one can let LaTeX figure out the entries.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgf}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\AdjEntry{%
\stepcounter{imat}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\irow}{(\value{imat}+2)/3}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\icol}{Mod(\value{imat}-1,3)+1}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\isign}{ifthenelse(pow(-1,\value{imat}+1)<0,"-","+")}%
\edef\temp{\noexpand\@removeelement{\icol}{1,2,3}{\noexpand\collst}%
\noexpand\@removeelement{\irow}{1,2,3}{\noexpand\rowlst}}%
\temp
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\ione}{{\rowlst}[0]}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\itwo}{{\rowlst}[1]}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\jone}{{\collst}[0]}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\jtwo}{{\collst}[1]}%
\isign 
\begin{vmatrix}
                a_{\jone\ione} & a_{\jtwo\ione} \\
                a_{\jone\itwo} & a_{\jtwo\itwo}
\end{vmatrix}}
\newcommand\aentry{\stepcounter{imat}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\irow}{(\value{imat}+2)/3}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\icol}{Mod(\value{imat}-1,3)+1}%
a_{\irow\icol}}
\makeatother
\newcounter{imat}
\begin{document}
\[\setcounter{imat}{0}
\operatorname{adj}\begin{pmatrix}
 \aentry & \aentry & \aentry\\
 \aentry & \aentry & \aentry\\
 \aentry & \aentry & \aentry\\
\end{pmatrix}=\setcounter{imat}{0}
\begin{pmatrix}
 \AdjEntry & \AdjEntry & \AdjEntry\\[2.5ex]
 \AdjEntry & \AdjEntry & \AdjEntry\\[2.5ex]
 \AdjEntry & \AdjEntry & \AdjEntry\\
\end{pmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, there is a missing `\mathbf{adj}` before the first matrix.

Comment: @Sebastiano Nope, you are 2 seconds late. ;-)

Comment: Did you read my mind? Hahahah. But it is in math-bold.

Comment: @Sebastiano No, my crystal ball got stolen.

Comment: Did the cat stole it? Hahahah

Comment: @Sebastiano I am a cat. I think the anteater has it.

Comment: @wipet I must say that I am a bit surprised by your statement. The statement that LaTeX is figuring out what the matrix entries are is a true statement. It does not exclude the possibility that this can also work with TeX. So far this is only logic. Now, as for the TeXnicalities: while it is certainly possible to do that with TeX, but the above code uses, for instance, `\@removeelement`, which is to the best of my knowledge a LaTeX2e macro, so I do not see what you do not like about my statement.

Comment: Thanks to everyone! :)

Comment: @wipet Everyone knows the history of TeX and LaTeX, I think. If you do not like the fact that this is a LaTeX code, this is fine. Claiming that this is a TeX code would suggest that you can compile this with plain TeX, which is at least misleading. I would kindly ask you to acknowledge that I have the right to write answers in the way that I think are correct. If you say that `{...\choose ...}` is a clearer notation, that's your opinion in your answer, and no one will ask you to change this even though some may not agree.

Answer (score 3):

We are using TeX, so we can do a shortcuts:

```
$$
\def\subd#1#2#3#4{\left|\matrix{a_{#1#2}&a_{#1#4}\cr a_{#3#2}&a_{#3#4}}\right|}
\def\crs{\cr\noalign{\kern.7ex}}
{\bf adj} \pmatrix{a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}\cr a_{21}&a_{22}&a_{23}\cr a_{31}&a_{32}&a_{33}}
= \pmatrix{+\subd 22 33 & -\subd 12 33 & +\subd 12 23 \crs
           -\subd 21 33 & +\subd 11 33 & -\subd 11 23 \crs
           +\subd 21 32 & -\subd 11 32 & +\subd 11 22} 
$$
```